# Add incremental custom attribute using Laravel model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, custom-attribute

I know how to add custom attribute using Laravel model. Does the same concept apply when we want to add incremental custom attribute as well?

```
/**Controller*/

$data = Model::select('*')->get(); //please ignore this line
            
//assuming that I want to append custom id & selected attribute to the model
$data->append('id')->toArray();         
$data->append('selected')->toArray();
```

```
/**Model*/

public function getSelectedAttribute()
{
    return false;
}

public function getIdAttribute()
{
    $increment = 0;
    $increment++;
    return $increment;
}
```

What I want to achieve:
id value will be increment ( 0, 1, .. n+1)

Example :

```
[
   {
        "column": "value",
        "id": 0,
        "selected": false
    },
    {
        "column": "value",
        "id": 1,
        "selected": false
    }
]
```

What I got:

```
[
   {
        "column": "value",
        "id": 0,
        "selected": false
    },
    {
        "column": "value",
        "id": 0,
        "selected": false
    }
]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Edit.
I used suggestion by Miqayel at this moment, and it works as intended.

```
static $increment = -13; // I need to change into -13 as the value starts on 13
$increment++;
return $increment;
```

Comment: Try declare as static `static $increment = 0;`

Comment: Thanks! It did incremented, but the value starts on 13 instead of 1. Anyway, thank you for your help.